# Recording flash in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

solutions for Two things :

1. Recording of flash objects in selenium IDE?
2. Getiing the flash objects ID through flash firebug?

I think these will be the two most things everyone need to be clarified.

I tried to record flash objects but it did'nt recognize even after adding the user -extension.js got from flex-api-0.25 zip file.

It says "We are unable to record the Flex object"

Also How to get the  flash object ID:

I installed Flash firebug and tried to find the ID so that i can Get the id and use in Selenium Rc. but happens like "I need to install flash played debugger above 10.Even after installing I was not able to identify the flash ID: it still says u need to install the flash player. I have installed 10.3 debugger.

Thanks in Advance!